# How to line this cake pan with parchment paper?

Tags: pan, parchment

This weird-shaped cake pan is difficult to use when it comes to the step that I must line it with parchment paper. How should I do it properly so that the cake will easily be removed from the pan?

[image]

Comment: A pan like this would normally be greased and floured, but you wouldn't line it with parchment. After the cake is done, you might put parchment over the top to aid in flipping it out though...

Comment: Do you have a specific recipe that's instructing you to line a bundt pan like this with parchment?  If so, I'd figure they would tell you the trick at the same time...

Comment: @logophobe: There is this vanilla cake recipe that I use as my favorite recipe and it says the pan should be lined with parchment paper and greased afterwards.

Comment: @Gigili The recipe is probably assuming that you're using a flat cake pan. I have never seen a bundt cake pan lined with parchment.

Comment: @Gigili : if it calls for using a 'tube pan', they likely mean a flat sided one, not a Bundt pan.

Comment: @Joe: Does it mean that I can bake that vanilla cake in a Bundt pan? Even with parchment paper, (disregarding how I lined the pan) the cake can't release. I wonder what should I do about this batter to have a clean surface when the cake is finished.

Comment: @Gigili The method in my answer should work. If not, there is something else going on.

Comment: @Gigili : that's probably worth asking as a question on its own -- typically for a bundt pan, you grease and flour it.  Once the cake's cooked, you can let it cool slightly, then use a dinner knife or narrow spatula to slowly pry the cake away from the pan.  Most bundt cakes are left unfrosted or a drizzled glaze.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't effectively line a Bundt pan with paper. My favorite method is to mix *cake release* and keep it in the cabinet. It lasts for months and months. Just mix 1 part vegetable oil, 1 part shortening and 1 part flour (roughly, by volume). Brush that mixture in the pan, getting all the nooks and crannies. It doesn't make the mess that traditional flouring does, I always end up getting flour everywhere doing it that way. I think the mixed ahead release works better too. It also doesn't show up on the cake as unmoistened flour. With your non-stick pan plus the cake release, you'll have no trouble.

OXO makes a silicone pastry brush that's great for this and all kinds of tasks, I use mine all the time. It goes in the dishwasher, it's heat resistant, it doesn't shed. It's a very handy little item. Look for the strips of silicone in between the bristles with holes that hold on to sauce.  You can see that in this picture using the magnification tool. [OXO Pastry Brush](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JPSI8C)

Comment: +1 for introducing the term "cake release" into my life.

Comment: Perhaps if you planned ahead you could make homemade paper using the pan as the mold, then impregnate it with silicon somehow... Yeah, I guess fat might work better.

Comment: Do you heat/melt the shortening during mixing? How does one ensure that it is fully mixed well?

Comment: @Phrogz. Nope, just mix it with a spoon. Do it once and you will see. It's slick (pun intended)

Comment: Does this cake release ever leave a white residue on the cake?

Comment: @mrog No, it doesn't leave white residue. That's one of the huge advantages, even on dark devil's food cake.

Answer (score 6):

It would appear the pan is non stick, in which case buttering and flouring it should be sufficient. The only way to line it with parchment would involve using multiple separate sheets, which might cause weird batter leakages between the sheets.