# Decrease stickiness of brownies during depanning?

Tags: brownies

I use a square pan with 12 slots to individually bake brownies, as opposed to using a large square pan. My problem is that during depanning, I would occassionally lose a brownie because of a sticky bottom (maybe underbaked).

What I normally do is pass a knife multiple times around each brownie so it comes off the sides, however this takes too much time, as opposed to the Anna Olson youtube video where she just slides in a pastry spatula and it came off so easily. What should be a 20-minute brownie batter is already running into half an hour.

How can I make this task easier? Should I:

1. Place it more towards the bottom of the oven and increase temp or time?
2. Use flavorless oil inside the slots?
3. Or cut out parchment paper that can fit inside the slots? (already too laborious..)

Grateful for anyone who can offer wisdom.

Comment: Sometimes I bake right after preparing the dough, sometimes I bake after refrigerating, scooping and rolling into balls, then freezing for a day or two. Still the same problem.

Comment: If it were in one large pan, I'd have recommended making a sling of parchment paper to help you remove it from the pan.  as it's 12 individual slots, all that I can say is make sure it's greased well.  You might want to try cake release : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/44692/67

Comment: Are you using the recipe from the YouTube Video?

Comment: I'd probably switch to using a large pan and a foil + parchment sling. You'll not get as many edge pieces as you would in your current setup, but it will be way easier to remove. If you want individual sized brownies, using foil liners in a muffin/cupcake tin might be a better option (albeit not traditionally rectangularly shaped).

Comment: @Joe, that's an interesting suggestion. I've never heard of cake release before, and I'm willing to try it.

Comment: @Catjia, yes I did follow the youtube video (as I was just beginning then), but the recipe has been modified many batters since.

Comment: @Batman, I'm close to using cut out parchment for the bottoms of the slots, and your suggestion of foil also has some potential. I'll try the cake release first.